# Can't .get() with multiple query params

Tags: jquery

I have been flabbergasted with this problem since yesterday

```
$('input').click(function(){
    var suggid;
    var state;
    suggid = $(this).attr("data-notifid");
    state = $(this).attr("checked");
    $.get('/notifications/toggle_read/', {suggestion_id: suggid, unread: state});
});
```

I've been trying to send `suggestion_id` and `unread` to my endpoint in a Django app. In a previous iteration, I was also trying `state = $(this).checked;`, since code samples I was finding appeared to do that.

The problem is that *I have been testing this code and making minor tweaks maybe about 50 times, and it has only ever sent `unread` once, when I hardcoded it to `"1"`.* Every single other request logged out as something like this: `GET /notifications/toggle_read/?suggestion_id=31` both in my runserver logs and in the console.

I always refreshed the page on which the script appeared before testing the code on the widget, and even confirmed it was up-to-date in the browser source. I'm baffled... according to what I've read about `.get()`, this is exactly how you're supposed to send multiple query parameters e.g.

`$.get( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );` at [this doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Is your checkbox actually checked when you click on it? You're applying the behaviour to **all** `<input>` elements, not just checkboxes. You also are applying it directly, which won't work if the element is dynamically created.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yep.

Comment: Please tell me the answer isn't spaces around stuff, because after I did that, things are starting to work :(

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yes,  the only inputs on the page are a big list of entries, each one having a checkbox. Unless there's [another way I can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858566/how-do-you-write-a-script-referencing-indexed-inputs) I thought it was workable. Maybe another misunderstanding on my part is that I will have to somehow update the checked attribute on the input as well, when clicks occur.

Comment: Try changing `$(this).attr("data-notifid")` to `$(this).data("notifid")` and `$(this).attr("checked")` to `$(this).prop("checked")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prop('checked')` to get the current value of the checkbox.  The attribute on the element does not update.  The property on the DOM element does.

```js
$('input').on('click', function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  console.log($this.attr('checked'), $this.prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked="false">
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not understand this attribute-property distinction before. That was very important for making the code work.

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of the checkbox as boolean, use

```
state = $(this).is(":checked");
```

instead of `attr("checked")` then use the value as the parameter for the GET request

Comment: Also very helpful: I didn't realize I needed to do this. I really wish I could give two checks..